# WebApi cors for runtime 4.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api, cors

I need WebApi Cors dll for web api project. I installed Web Api version for .net 4 framework, because I use VS 2010. I tried to install web api cors lib via nuget (Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors), and this error is shown "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.1.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework".
Is there workaround to install Cors for web api client 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CORS is supported in Web API 2 that needs .NET Framework 4.5 and visual studio/express 2014.

It is not available for Web API 1

Comment: this tutorial may help on this [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Answer (score 2):

CORS is natively supported in Web API 2 only. However, you can write your own extensions. Take a look at [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CORS-support-in-ASPNET-Web-01e9980a) tutorial by Carlos Figueira. The tutorial not only applies to the RC version but also to final version 1.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check EF version before inastalling above package if it is EF version 4.5 and above then it works otherwise it rollbacks below EF version 4.5

And  ** Access-Control-Allow-Origin ** problem is solved no need to do extra work

and you can do it in **VS 2013 web express**

```
using System.Web.Http.Cors;
namespace WebApplication10
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
            config.EnableCors(cors);
            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this will help
 Thank you

This is WebApiConfig.cs file

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

and  `using System.Web.Http.Cors;`

these are the changes you need to do.
**For Api Controller**

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{

    // GET api/<controller>
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
```

just add [HttpGet] attribute and all is set.

Answer (score 1):

For IIS 6 servers:

To CORS-enable Microsoft IIS6, perform the following steps:

- Open Internet Information Service (IIS) Manager
- Right click the site you want to enable CORS for and go to Properties
- Change to the HTTP Headers tab In the Custom HTTP headers section, click Add
- Enter Access-Control-Allow-Origin as the header name
- Enter * as the header value
- Click Ok twice

*http://enable-cors.org/server_iis6.html*

Comment: We are restricted to .NET 4.0, so this helped me.

Answer (score 1):

**For IIS7**

Merge this into the web.config file at the root of your application / site:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <system.webServer>
      <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
          <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
  </configuration>
```

[sourced from w3](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CORS_Enabled#For_IIS7)

Comment: This is what worked for me in the end, in my .net framework 4 project. Thanks.